# How to dynamically build an array of crossfilter groups?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, dc.js

I have a crossfilter data structure with partly unknown columns.

I want to draw a composite dc.js chart with the ability to dynamically switch on and off the y-Dimensions.

Therefore I try to build an array of groups for every column:

```
this.data = crossfilter(this.rawData);

this.idDimension = this.data.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.id;
});

for (var property in this.rawData[0]) {
    this.groups[property] = this.idDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d[property];
    });
}
```

The problem is that each group works on the column of the last property in the loop.

How can I circumvent this? Or are there better ways to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the variable scope.

A solution I've found works this way:

```
var createPropertyGroup = function(dimension, property) {
    return dimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
            return d[property];
        });
}

for (var property in this.rawData[0]) {
    this.groups[property] = createPropertyGroup(this.idDimension, property);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps in your case, but you can also add multiple properties to the same group.

```
    teamMemberGroup = teamMemberDimension.group().reduce(

    function (p, d) {
        p.count++;
        p.name = d.name;
        p.salary = d.salary;
        p.start_date = d.start_date;
        return p;
    },

    function (p, d) {
        p.count--;
        return p;
    },

    function () {
        return {count: 0, name: "", salary: 0, p.start_date = null};
    });
```

The valueAccessor method for DCCharts can be used to differentiate between different y values for different charts.

```
teamMemberChart
        .dimension(teamMemberDimension)
        .group(teamMemberGroup)
        .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.count;
    })
```

Depending on your case, this might help simplify your code and *might* improve performance.